# Run exe after installation with user rights

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project, credentials

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on windows 7 and developing a windows forms application in c# with a setup project ( msi ) that comes with visual studio.

I have added a custom action :

```
        protected override void OnCommitted(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnCommitted(savedState);
        Process.Start(@"Path");
    }
```

But when my application starts, it starts with the user "NTSYSTEM". I want it to start with the logged in windows user account instead.

How can i manage that?

Thank you.

Comment: The code i am showing is the way to start an application after setup is complete with custom actions.

Comment: You should be able to determine the username of the user by using the using a method to locate say the user's application data folder. I would imagine the reason the process is starting as NTSYSTEM is because that is indeed the profile the installer uses at that point. Could just provide a shortcut on the desktop?  Your original question was asking about Windows Phone 7....

Comment: You shouldn't, in general, perform operations during installation that must be done in the context of the user logged on when installation was performed. What if some admin installed the software and handed it back to one of the users. Instead perform these actions the first time any user runs the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...

Added a javascript to run the program in the Post-Build property for the setup project and it started as a user instead of the system.

Answer (score 1):

3 posible solutions:

1) Login the application with whatever user you want via [advapi32.dll](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html), this requires that you either know the users login or that he inputs it.
2) Even cruder you can use [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) to run the application, and again user either inputs the username and password or  you do it.
3) You place the application in the automatic startup on the computer, (perhaps force a reboot ? ) and it will run in user context on reboot.